# bash: get array name from parameter to function with saving indexes

Tags: bash, function, array

I have a function to show index of chosen element. I'm trying to pass a parameter to function to use it as an array name. This works:

```
getIndex() {
arrname=$1[@]
b=("${!arrname}")
index=1; while ((index<${#b[@]})); do
    if [[ "${b[$index]}" = "$VALUE" ]]; then
        echo "index is $index"; return
    fi  
        ((index++)); done

}
```

But the array, whose name I pass to this function, has index 1 as index of first element (I need this to have indexes similar to line numbers, from which I get patterns in the array:

```
a=1
while read line; do
    if [[ $line =~ ^[0-9] ]]; then
        avg[$a]=`echo $line | awk '{print $6}'`
        ((a++));    
    fi
```

And if I'm running function getIndex() the first element of the array starts from index 0.

So, the question is: Is there any way to pass array name in parameter to function with saving indexes of array?
Or maybe I just need to forget about it and add +1 to function answer.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in Bash are zero-based. They just are. That said, if you **know** that the array is always going to be indexed by numbers starting from 1, just add +1 to the result. Add a second argument to the function, that will tell it what number to start from or add to the result, and add a sensible default for cases where the second argument is missing. Or loop over indices as [mr.spuratic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/94746/22886) suggests.

Comment: Unfortunately without `declare -A` you always get normal indexed arrays. It's just a non-contiguous one. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html.

Answer (score 1):

You are using this construction:

```
b=("${!arrname}")
```

This expands the *values* of the array, creating a new array `b[]` with *the bash default array indexes starting from 0*. To properly initialise a copy of the array you would 
need to restore the indexes (e.g. by parsing or `eval`-ing the output of `declare -p arrname`)

Rather than making a copy, a better approach is to expand the *indexes* rather than the values, and iterate over the array using those. This approach will work with sparse, or non-zero based standard arrays (and even bash4 associative arrays).

The catch (isn't there always) is that the `!` is pulling double duty: its use in indirection `${!name}` is not compatible with its use for expanding array indexes `${!arrname[@]}`, so we have to use `eval`.

Here's a modified version which implements this:

```
getIndex2() {
  local arrname=$1 iidx idxs index ival val
  printf -v iidx '"${!%s[@]}"' "$arrname"
  eval "idxs=($iidx)"
  for index in "${idxs[@]}"; do
    printf -v ival '${%s[%s]}' "$arrname" "$index"
    eval "val=$ival"
    if [[ "${val}" = "$VALUE" ]]; then
        echo "index is $index"; return   
    fi
  done
}
```

Note the use of `printf -v var ...` (bash-3.1+) to try to keep the `eval` readable.
The indexes are expanded into an array, this is not strictly necessary, a flat list would do also.

See also [BashFAQ/006](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006).